# Table cells autosize without setting width

Tags: html, css

I would like to set autosizing of td in table. But i don't want to set any width. Is it possible that table will "know" there are 3 td and everyone should have 33% width?

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>width: 33%;</td>
      <td>width: 33%;</td>
      <td>width: 33%;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `table-layout:fixed;` property

```
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `table-layout:fixed;` and `width:100%;` to `table`

```css
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>width: 33%;</td>
      <td>width: 33%;</td>
      <td>width: 33%;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```